# In SharePoint 2013 Online, how can I exclude the term "SharePoint" from searching the base URL?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

We have a SharePoint 2013 site running on Office 365.  When a user searches "`SharePoint`", it will return every item with a URL containing "`[companyname].sharepoint.com`", which is every item and folder.  Is it possible to exclude the words "`SharePoint`" or "`[companyname]`" from referencing the Base URL?

Answer (score 1):

you can update the search results webpart to exclude the word tree by

- go to the search results page
- edit the page
- edit the search result webparts
- click change query
- add (and -SharePoint) to exclude the keyword from the search see image
  below
  [image]

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4fcde10-341b-4e76-8806-99ab74aa7114/removing-term-from-search-office-365-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearch

http://www.mavention.com/blog/exclude-external-users-search-results-office-365

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This definitely works if I want the term" SharePoint" to return no results.  However, items exist in the system with SharePoint in the Title or Filename and it would be nice to have those show up when SharePoint is searched.

Comment: then try to put the url and see the results.

Comment: Please see the following images:
 [_Searching "sharepoint"_](http://screencast.com/t/N4hk2y9wYUJ2) |
 [_Searching "Title:sharepoint"_](http://screencast.com/t/a8dbUD4n). 
My goal is not to completely exclude the term sharepoint but I need to ignore the base URL.